# Asus ME 172v usb debugging in MAC

Tags: android, macos, adb, usb-debugging, asus

I am using`ASUS Memo Pad ME172V`.

I am using Android Studio for application Development in MAC.

When i am plugging my USB Cable in MAC,then my device is not getting listed in devices available for debugging.
Can anyone provide any inputs on this?

Comment: Some usb cables are for charging only. Or you haven't enabled usb debugging on the device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am using the same cable and device in Windows 7

Comment: Okay... Does the problem also happen there?

Comment: No never. I have never faced such issue in Windows but I still can't access it. I have tried other phones also and they are working fine.

Comment: Have you enabled ADB debugging and cleared the USB debugging authorizations?

Comment: how can we do this. I have never done this before

Comment: You can find may links on how to "enable developer options" on the Web. If you haven't done that and actually enabled USB debugging, then I'm not surprised it doesnt work for that device

Comment: I have enabled developer options. In this tab Developer Options are already enabled by default. I was using it in windows and there was not such error

Comment: If you have enabled USB debugging, and it does not appear from `adb devices`, then I'm not sure what the problem is. OS X has the Android File Transfer tool, but other than that, the terminal, and Android Studio, there aren't many options to diagnose the problem

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the support

Comment: exact same issue with this device, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok found a solution for this, a custom built adb binary.
Such as the one provided [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B936USMlQhtKbmZLZDE3N1JMazA/view)

So using the `adb.mac` file provided execute `adb.mac devices` command in the terminal, it will shut down your currently running adb server and restart it's own. The basic idea seems to be that this Asus device has an intel chipset, so googling their most popular x86 phone : zenfone2  with adb you can find a cutom adb such as the one I linked to. More info on `Building adb and fastboot command from AOSP source code`, can be found [here](http://corochann.com/building-adb-and-fastboot-command-from-aosp-source-code-478.html). In short a custom AOSP on a device seems to in rare cases require a custom adb, at least on OSX. Hope this helps!